# jquery обработчик (при смене текста)

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность определять изменился ли текст, допустим в `<div id="error">` ?

Comment: Каким образом там может измениться текст?

Comment: при $.ajax запросе, но если на success вешаешь визуальный эффект, например $('#errors').show(1500); то анимация проигрывается только один раз!?

Comment: А сколько раз она должна проигрываться? :) Может просто проверять состояние #errors, и если он уже показан, то скрыть его и снова показать?..

Comment: ах да, совсем забыл, 

$.ajax обрабатывается при $('#form').change(function(){ 
, так вот я ожидал что при каждом изменении в форме, будет проигрываться анимация...

Comment: Т.е. если у вас пять полей ввода и пользователь ввел только в первое и перескочил на второе, то для оставшихся четырех будет выскакивать ошибка типа "Пустое поле недопустимо"? Очень разумно!

Comment: хм, ну догадки строить не стоило, надо было спросить о том, для чего мне это!

у меня калькулятор, который состоит из чекбоксов, при изменении состояния чекбоксов нужно выводить различные сообщения, типа если выбран 1 и 3 чекбоксы - вывести "Отличный выбор", а если выбран 2 и 4 - написать "Плохой выбор", например...

Comment: Догадки начинаются с вопросов, которые описывают слишком общий случай. Возможно, вам следует писать вопросы поподробней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Здравствуйте*

Проверить можно, просто вытянув этот текст и сравнить его

```
var newtext = $('#error').text();
if(newtext == 'text'){
  alert('новый текст');
}
```

Comment: а с чем сравнивать? сообщения всегда разные и могу выводиться в любом порядке! загонять в куку последнее? не очень мне кажется...

Comment: Смотря для чего вам нужно сравнение, если на проверку заполненых полей, то так не пойдет, и ваш вариант тоже не пойдет!